# A question about "if clauses"

Tags: conditional-constructions

I read below in Oxford English Grammar Course, Micheal Swan & Catherine Walter:

> He **won't** come tomorrow if he **came** yesterday.

I'd like to know more explanation about this. What type of conditional is it? And, I've never seen "future tense" and "past tense in "if sentence".

Thank you.

Comment: It's just an ordinary conditional proposition, although with one negative term, in the form of "if A then not B," inverted to "not B if A." The future and past are irrelevant to the form of the conditional, but properly handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> He won't come tomorrow if he came yesterday.
>
> If he came yesterday, he won't come tomorrow.

This form of **if** can be semantically equivalent to "since" or "given (the fact)":

> He won't come tomorrow, *since* he came yesterday.
>
> *Since* he came yesterday, he won't come tomorrow.

(For example, he has already made his weekly visit.)

> There's no reason to expect him to come again tomorrow, given the fact that he was here yesterday.
>
> Given the fact that he was here yesterday, there's no reason to expect him to come again tomorrow.

But the factualness of the condition need not be known:

> If the train broke down a mile south of us, it won't be arriving on
>   time.

There, the future tense **won't** refers to what will not take place if it turns out to be true that the train did break down.

Comment: Hmm ... *if* is equivalent to *since* only if it is known that he came yesterday.

Comment: I saw him with my own eyes.